# Matplotlib plotting Julian Days in X values python

Tags: python, matplotlib, days, julian-date

Good day, I am having issues plotting the bar graph x values from 16000 to 17000, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
plt.title("Site Data Availability")
plt.xlabel("Julian Year Dates (YYDDD)")
plt.ylabel("Instrument Sites")
plt.axhline(y="BTK", color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=10)
plt.axhline(y="BTK", xmin=16000, xmax=17000, color='b', linestyle='-', linewidth=10) #issues with this line
plt.xlim(15000, 20000)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Comment: what are you getting? what do you want?

Comment: This is an image to visually explain it for simplification: https://imgur.com/a/XF1Ew1N

Comment: @AndyB please, increment your question in a way it's complete. Here you have a good explanation on what is a "good question": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For example, add the link you gave at the comment, also include a working snippet of code - with all imports required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hlines`:

```
plt.title("Site Data Availability")
plt.xlabel("Julian Year Dates (YYDDD)")
plt.ylabel("Instrument Sites")
plt.axhline(y="BTK", color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=10)
plt.hlines(y="BTK", xmin=16000, xmax=17000, color='b', linestyle='-', linewidth=10, zorder=10) #issues with this line
plt.xlim(15000, 20000)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

#### Where

- axhline -- Add a horizontal line across the axis.
- hlines --  Add horizontal lines in data coordinates. Plot
  horizontal lines at each y from xmin to xmax.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your line for:

```
plt.axhline(y="BTK", xmin=.2, xmax=.4, color='b', linestyle='-', linewidth=10)
```

Explaning: 
`xmin` and `xmax` must be a value between 0 and 1.

In your code, 0 is represented by 15000 and 1 corresponds to 20000.

You can use a linear interpolator and found out the % of 16000 (0.2) and 17000 (0.4).

Comment: This is an image to visually explain it for simplification: imgur.com/a/XF1Ew1N

Comment: Updated my answer. Check out and let me know if it works for you.